# Elegant pattern in the standard London Dartboard$?$

Tags: recreational-mathematics

The image below is of a standard dartboard

[image]

---

I was just wondering why this sequence of numbers was used in the first place. Is there any special and beautiful sequence hidden in this dartboard$?$ I tried finding some by experimenting with the squares of those numbers but couldn't find one. Can anyone spot any elegant pattern$?$

Comment: The intention was likely to have been to put low numbers adjacent to high numbers (and perhaps odd numbers next to $20$) to penalise inaccuracy, but there is no claim that the standard pattern is optimal in any sense.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darts#Dartboard) and especially the references in [footnote A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darts#cite_note-7)